# Unresolved Reference en Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, kotlin, login

```
    package com.example.myapplication

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.ContactsContract
import android.text.Editable
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main3.*

    enum class ProviderType{
        BASIC
    }




class Homeactivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3)
        val bundle =intent.extras
        bundle?.getString("email")
        bundle?.getString("provider")

        setup(email?: "", provider?: "")
    }
    private fun setup(email:String, provider: String){
        title ="Inicio"
        emailTextEdit.setText(email)
        providerTextEdit.setText(provider)
    }
}
```

En el código de `setup(email?: "", provider?: "")` email y provider me dan un error de Unresolved Reference, y ya no sé que hacer, llevo haciendo búsquedas exhaustas desde hace timepo y no encuentro información, si alguien puede ayudarme estaría muy agradecido.

Answer (score 1):

Obtienes el error

> Unresolved Reference

Debido a que no estas definiendo las variables. Al obtener los valores del bundle, esta es la forma como debes recibir los valores y asignarlos al método:

```
var bundle :Bundle ?=intent.extras
var email = bundle!!.getString("email") 
var provider= bundle!!.getString("provider") 

setup(email?: "", provider?: "")
```